# Python: Find all possible vector combinations from 2D array points stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary that stores 2D array datapoints like this:

```
centroids = {0: array([ 8, 9]),
          1: array([ 4, 14]),
          2: array([ 2, 11]),
          3: array([19, 11]),
          4: array([15, 10]),
          5: array([ 2, 12])}
```

To find the vector between two points, you subtract the initial point from ending point. However, I want to find all the possible vectors that result from these array values, such as the vector from the keys 0 to 1, 0 to 2, 0 to 3, 4 to 5, etc.

For example: I want it to output something like:

```
result = {0 to 1: [-4,5],
          0 to 2: [-6,2],
          0 to 3: [11,2]....}
```

Is there a pythonic way to do this with the minimal amount of for loops?

Comment: don't try to look for a pythonic way at the start. try to do it yourself with loops

Answer (score 0):

```
centroid_coordinates = []
for i in centroids.values():
  centroid_coordinates.append(i)

differences = []
for i in range(len(centroid_coordinates)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(centroid_coordinates)):
        diff = (centroid_coordinates[i][0] - centroid_coordinates[j][0], 
        centroid_coordinates[i][1] - centroid_coordinates[j][1])
        differences.append(diff)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).